# Balancing PHP SDK and Cloud Code

Tags: php, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Recently I decided to develop a web application about giving away accounts for a game (a meta-community) and chose Parse as my backend service. I was a newbie in network security. At first I implemented all the authentication as variable in client code and soon realized by myself that I could bypass them easily.

Then I moved every authentication step to Cloud Code, set up CLP and ACL. Now the client is only responsible for collecting data, putting them as parameters and calling Cloud Functions, and finally receiving the response and represent it. This was all achieved through pure JavaScript (both client and cloud code).

Now come the other part: PHP. My friend has always advised to try working with PHP instead. I also have my own dedicated server which supports PHP (and also an SQL database, but we are not going into that). Now I'm really teared up as I'm aware of some limitations with Cloud Code (like execution time limit).

So my question is, what can PHP and Cloud Code do that the other cannot, and should I be too worried about either one of them? Also, if you use Parse, what responsibility do you often give to PHP and Cloud Code?

EDIT: the code is not really relevant but I will try to provide some examples. This is a code segment in the client side:

```
$('#login').click(function () {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            Parse.Cloud.run("facebookAuth", fbResponse.authResponse, {
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("User logged in through Facebook!");
                    Parse.User.become(response.sessionToken).then(function (loggedUser) {
                        // The current user is now set to user.
                        console.log("facebookAuth: Authentication completed.");
                        activityLog("User logged in through Facebook!");
                    }, function (error) {
                        // The token could not be validated.
                        console.log("The token could not be validated.");
                        activityLog("An error has occurred: " + error);
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    activityLog("You need to be a group member to use the application!");
                    Parse.User.logOut();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the Cloud Functions for them:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("facebookAuth", function (fbAuthRes, response) {
    // I implement the Facebook authentication here.
    // If user is logged into Facebook (and is member of my group), then the user is logged in then:
    response.success({user: user, sessionToken: user.getSessionToken()});
    // The full code is too long.
}
```

Comment: Please make your question more specific and include some `code` that you tried to achieve your goals.

Comment: Cloud Code seems intended to provide the ability to run a Parse app with server-side processing without needing a server. If you have a server already, chances are either one is a viable option and there'll be few significant differences.